# Get focus of other application from Vb.net Service

Tags: vb.net, service

I have got a vb.net windows service that runs a File System Watcher to monitor an xml file for changes, when it detects a change it will stop the screen saver running and what I would then like it to do is give one of the other running applications the focus.

I have successfully used Appactivate from a Windows Form App in the past but I think I am correct in saying this doesn't work with Windowless applications (I have tried it and it doesn't).

I have done some Googling but I can't seem to find any way of getting the focus when called from a service \ windowless app.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What user account is the service running under? Probably not the current interactive user, which means that it has no access to the current interactive user's session.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The service is running as local system, I have tried changing the user to the current user but this didn't make any difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

what if you make it a single instance application? and then simply launch its .exe file? it might give focus to the other running application instead of opening a new instance.